# Way to clean all info from my store keeping just the template

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento store, and my products, customer and lot of other information, have several problems becouse i make a importantion and this importantion broke all.

But my store already have the layout and template are ok. I want just clean all registers from products clientes and every else and keep just the "face" of store.

It's possible??

Comment: Are you trying to delete all customers, products, categories, orders etc... with the exception of your templates files?

Comment: Yes, i want to keep just the template files and template configurations CMS pages. @R.S, its just clean the store starting from zero exept the template and all info need to template works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either

1. Install a fresh copy of magento and rsync over the template files (drawback - you would need to update core_config, cms and system config).
2. Truncate the various tables

   - [customers.sql, logs.sql and sales.sql](https://gist.github.com/leek/1219708)
   - [Products and categories](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/import-export_and_data_manipulation/removing_products_through_the_database)

Remember to backup your db